# Search between specific words in Word document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

This macro searches for words through the Word document: `Set r = WordDoc.Range`. Is it possible to make it search only between specific words in Word document? Example: search only from "Word1" to "Word2". I know that I need to find these words and set them as Range.Start and Range.End, but i'm not good at this. Can someone help me with code?

```
Sub test()
Dim Word As Object, WordDoc  As Object
Dim r As Boolean, f As Boolean, fO As Long
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Filename:=Application.ThisWorkbook.path & "\test.docx")

'''name'''
Set r = WordDoc.Range
Do While UnifiedSearch(r, "name*book1")
    If f Then
        If r.Start = fO Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Else
        fO = r.Start
        f = True
    End If
    WordDoc.Range(r.Start + 4, r.End - 5).Copy
    Range("C4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Set r = WordDoc.Range(r.End, r.End)
Loop

WordDoc.Close
Word.Quit

End Sub

Private Function UnifiedSearch(r As Range, s As String) As Boolean

     With r.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = s
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        UnifiedSearch = .Execute
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? It's not clear whether you mean the first and second words in the document, or text that's literally "Word 1" and "Word 2"? You also don't give us any information as to values for f and f0.

Comment: Literally "Word 1" and "Word 2".

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/1059223-search-between-specific-words-word-document.html
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear what all your code is supposed to be doing, but I changed the first part to search the two terms, then set the range to be searched to everything between the two terms (including the terms, themselves). I used multiple ranges so that it's always clear what Range refers to which content.

I had to make some corrections to your code, for example you declared `r` as a Boolean, when it should be a Word.Range. I also had to change the object of the Word application since a Range needs to be declared using Word.Range in order to distinguish in from an Excel Range. Or you need to change these declarations to `Object` if you don't set a reference to Word's object library.

Notice how the `Duplicate` property needs to be used in order to "copy" a Range to an independent Range object.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wd As Object, WordDoc  As Object
    Dim r As Word.Range, f As Boolean, fO As Long
    Dim rStart As Word.Range, rEnd As Word.Range, rSearch As Word.Range

    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = wd.Documents.Open(Filename:=Application.ThisWorkbook.path & "\test.docx")

    '''name'''
    Set r = WordDoc.content
    Set rStart = r.Duplicate
    If Not UnifiedSearch(rStart, "Word 1") Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set rEnd = rStart.Duplicate
    rEnd.End = r.End

    If Not UnifiedSearch(rEnd, "Word 2") Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set rSearch = r.Duplicate
    rSearch.Start = rStart.Start
    rSearch.End = rEnd.End

    Do While UnifiedSearch(rSearch, "name*book1")
        If f Then
            If r.Start = fO Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            fO = r.Start
            f = True
        End If
        WordDoc.Range(r.Start + 4, r.End - 5).Copy
        Range("C4").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Set r = WordDoc.Range(r.End, r.End)
    Loop
'

    WordDoc.Close
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    wd.Quit
    Set wd = Nothing

End Sub

Private Function UnifiedSearch(ByRef r As Range, s As String) As Boolean
    Dim found As Boolean

     With r.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = s
        .Forward = True
        .wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        found = .Execute
    End With
    Debug.Print found, s
        UnifiedSearch = found

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I changed Word.Range to Object. But the macro dont paste the word i need: `"name * book1"`, which it should be found in the range of these words: `"Word 1"` and `"Word 2"` but paste the entire text of the document with error: `Run-time Error 4608 Value out of Range`.

Comment: I assume the problem to which you're referring occurs further down in your code. I can't speak to that since you provide absolutely no way to reproduce running that part of your code. We have no idea what `f` or `f0` are. Nor can I know what changes you may have made to the line(s) that follow. You do need to change your code following what I added - I only provided the steps to get `rSearch`. Beyond that I couldn't go since the second part is not clear. I mentioned that in my Answer.